# SwiftUI Can't Put Sections Inside Other Containers

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to optimize the layout of a Detail view for iPad in a SwiftUI NavigationSplitView.
I crafted the Detail view to show an Image at the top, then each attribute of a
data model in a Section with a header. That all works, but when I attempt to put the
image and a few of the attributes in an HStack so they are side by side (in an iPad)
I lose all of the Section formatting. The data still exists, just not formatted as
sections. I've tried many combinations of surrounding containers - VStack, Form,
List, Group, another Section but nothing works. I have not been able to find any
literature that says what I am trying will not work.

Here's a simplified version. This example does not even use the NavigationSplitView -
and it still breaks.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let thingOne = Thing(name: "One", source: "Source One", category: "Category One", owner: "Owner One")

    var body: some View {
        List {
        //1
            //HStack { uncomment this and the formatting breaks
                Group1()
                Group2(thing: thingOne)
            //}
            Group3(thing: thingOne)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .padding()
    }//body

    struct Group1: View {
        var body: some View {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height:  150)
        }
    }//group 1

    struct Group2: View {
        var thing: Thing
    
        var body: some View {
            Section {
                Text(thing.name)
            } header: {
                Text("Thing Name:")
            }//section
        
            Section {
                Text(thing.source)
            } header: {
                Text("Thing Source:")
            }//section
        }
    }//group 2

    struct Group3: View {
        var thing: Thing
    
        var body: some View {
            Section {
                Text(thing.category)
            } header: {
                Text("Thing Cateogry:")
            }//section
        
            Section {
                Text(thing.owner)
            } header: {
                Text("Thing Owner:")
            }//section
        }
    }//group 3

}//content view

struct Thing: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let source: String
    let category: String
    let owner: String
}//struct thing
```

Comment out the HStack at //1:

[image]

Uncomment HStack at //1:

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 14 beta 6, iOS 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SwiftUI doc, you're advised to use Sections inside supported parent views such as List, Picker, and Form.
([Use Section instances in views like List, Picker, and Form to organize content into separate sections.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section))

The issue is that you're trying to divide unsupported views into sections. Native containers such as Sections sometimes have strict constraints to allow a more consistent design system.

Try putting sections inside a List, and it should work as you've desired, although in this case I would build a custom section view.

```
    struct Group2: View {
    var thing: Thing

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // Assuming you want to put two Sections horizontally (which is not the best usage of SwiftUI native sections)
            // You can put two separate Lists inside HStack, and a section in each List.
            List {
                Section {
                    Text(thing.name)
                } header: {
                    Text("Thing Name:")
                }//section
            }
            List {
                Section {
                    Text(thing.name)
                } header: {
                    Text("Thing Name:")
                }//section

            }
        }
    }
}//group 2
```

[image: iPhone]
[image: iPad]

Comment: Understood. This works for me, and yes, I meant to have the sections to the right of the image in a VStack not an HStack.